# what wrong i am doing here? curunt time to 2 minutes countdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

what's wrongdoing here I am creating current time to 2 minutes countdown using moment js here I am phasing issues timer stop  at 1:59 not decrease time after 1:59

[image: you can see SS]

```
const CountDownTimer = () => {
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(null);

  const getFinalTime = useCallback((duration) => {
    const currentDuration = moment.duration(duration, "milliseconds");
    let finalMinutes = currentDuration?.minutes();
    let finalSeconds = currentDuration?.seconds();
    finalMinutes = finalMinutes < 10 ? `0${finalMinutes}` : finalMinutes;
    finalSeconds = finalSeconds < 10 ? `0${finalSeconds}` : finalSeconds;
    return `${finalMinutes}:${finalSeconds}`;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const startTimer = moment(billData?.createdAt);
    const endTimer = moment(billData?.createdAt).add(2, "minutes");
    const duration = moment.duration(endTimer.diff(startTimer), "milliseconds");
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const newDuration = moment
        .duration(duration - 1000, "milliseconds")
        .asMilliseconds();
      setDuration(newDuration);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [billData?.createdAt]);

  // in getFinalTime passing duration

  return <>{getFinalTime(duration)}</>;
};

export default CountDownTimer;
```

Comment: You're not telling us what there is wrong with it, so very hard to tell.

Comment: What's not working? Is there an error code? This needs more information.

Comment: @AKX description updated

Comment: @Kantivekariya You're not even using the `getFinalTime` function in the code you've pasted.

Comment: @AKX they just passing duration time

Comment: You added a line that calls `getFinalTime`, but you don't use the return value.  I highly doubt that's how your app works. Please edit your post to include all of the actual related code.

Comment: @AKX updated pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing a whole lot of unnecessary work for a countdown timer.

See below for a simple implementation.

- The timer component accepts a deadline `Date` object.
- The timer component has internal state that just ensures it gets updated every second by way of the effect.
- Computing the time left is a matter of computing the millisecond difference between the current time and the deadline, followed by a div/mod operation to extract minutes and seconds. (You could add another div/mod to get hours and minutes.)

```js
function CountdownTimer({ deadline }) {
  const [, setUpdate] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setUpdate((u) => u + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
  const timeLeftTotal = Math.max(
    0,
    Math.ceil((+deadline - +new Date()) / 1000)
  );
  const timeLeftMinutes = Math.floor(timeLeftTotal / 60);
  const timeLeftSeconds = timeLeftTotal % 60;
  const mmss = [timeLeftMinutes, timeLeftSeconds]
    .map((s) => String(s).padStart(2, "0"))
    .join(":");
  return <div>Time left: {mmss}</div>;
}

function getDeadline(secondsInFuture) {
  return new Date(+new Date() + secondsInFuture * 1000);
}

function App() {
  const [deadline, setDeadline] = React.useState(() => getDeadline(120));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CountdownTimer deadline={deadline} />
      <hr />
      <button onClick={() => setDeadline(getDeadline(60))}>
        Reset deadline to 1 minute in the future
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```